# How to store data from an UnsafeMutablePointer in the iOS file system

Tags: ios, swift, unsafe-pointers

I am reading data from an MFi external device into a buffer using a 3rd party SDK "sessionController". See below:

```
    let handle: UInt64 = self.sessionController.openFile(file.path, mode: openMode)
    if handle == 0 {
        //Error
        return
    }

    let c: UInt64 = file.size

    var bytesArray: [UInt8] = [UInt8](fileData)
    let bufferPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: Int(c))

    bufferPointer.initialize(repeating: 0, count: Int(c))

    defer {
        bufferPointer.deinitialize(count: Int(c))
        bufferPointer.deallocate()
    }

    var sum: UInt32 = 0
    let singleSize: UInt32 = 8 << 20

    while sum < c {
        let read = self.sessionController.readFile(handle, data: bufferPointer, len: singleSize)
        if read == 0 {
            //There was an error
            return
        }
        sum += read
    }

    let newPointer : UnsafeRawPointer = UnsafeRawPointer(bufferPointer)

    fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("test.MOV")

    fileData = Data(bytes: newPointer, count: Int(c))

    try! fileData.write(to: fileURL)

    //Now use this fileURL to watch video in an AVPlayer... 
    //AVPlayer(init: fileURL)
```

For some reason the data stored at the fileURL becomes corrupted (I think) and I am unable to play the video file. I think I am not doing something correctly with Unsafe Swift but I am not sure what. How can I make sure that I have properly read the data from the device into memory, and then taken that data from memory and stored it on the hard drive at the fileURL? What am I doing wrong here? The video will not play in AVPlayer given the fileURL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error is here:

```
let read = self.sessionController.readFile(handle, data: bufferPointer, len: singleSize)
```

If you read in multiple chunks then the second and all subsequent reads will *overwrite* the data read previously. So that should probably be

```
let read = self.sessionController.readFile(handle, data: bufferPointer + sum, len: singleSize)
```

Note also that the file size is defined as `UInt64`, but the variable `sum` (which holds the total number of bytes read so far) is an `UInt32`. This will lead to problems if there is more than 4GB data.

But generally I would avoid to read the complete data into a memory buffer. You already read in chunks, so you can write the data immediately to the destination file. Here is how that could look like:

```
// Output file:
let fileURL = ...
let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: fileURL)
defer { fileHandle.closeFile() }

// Buffer:
let bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 // Choose some buffer size
var buffer = Data(count: bufferSize)

// Read/write loop:
let fileSize: UInt64 = file.size
var remainingToRead = fileSize
while remainingToRead > 0 {
    let read = buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bufferPointer in
        self.sessionController.readFile(handle, data: bufferPointer, len: UInt32(min(remainingToRead, UInt64(bufferSize))))
    }
    if read == 0 {
        return // Read error 
    }
    remainingToRead -= UInt64(read)
    fileHandle.write(buffer)
}
```

Note also that the data is read directly into a `Data` value, instead of reading it into allocated memory and then copying it to another `Data`.